# Kotlin notebook not finding sources of local project

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, kotlin-notebook

I have a simple kotlin gradle project and I'd like to use the [Kotlin notebook](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/16340-kotlin-notebook) to try out quickly my code.

The Kotlin notebook is supposed to be able to access the sources of a local project but those can't actuallty be found:

[image]

Steps to reproduce:

- Generate a Gradle project

```
gradle init \
  --type kotlin-application \
  --dsl kotlin \
  --package my.project \
  --project-name my-project  \
  --no-split-project  \
  --java-version 17
```

- Add a `playground.ipynb` to the project

Comment: Would you add the content of your gradle file?

Comment: I am asking because I am wondering if `implementation group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', name: 'kotlin-script-runtime', version: '1.9.22'` is present as a dependency

Answer (score 0):

One has to go to the Kotlin Notebook settings on the top of the notebook to "Select modules to use in the Notebook". There I needed to select on which of my modules the notebook depends

[image]